# How Delete line In image with openCV

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have these images and I want to eliminate the lines that appear, so that the date remains without any other noise. How can I do it in python with openCV?

[1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9d3R.jpg)

[2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMOZa.jpg)

[3.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHzIc.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,100)
for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,255),10)

cv2.imwrite('output.jpg',img)
```

output: [image]

Comment: Excelent! thank you so much @Joy Mazumder, can you explain me how the cicle for works?